# Random string from randomly placed circles

Tags: security, math, multi-touch

I have this fun idea of a project i'd like to do, but i'm not really sure about the math part of it. Here is the idea:

- Make a plastic card that would simulate a 9 finger multitouch gesture when it is held against a capacitive screen
- Based on the "9 finger" placement, determine some sort of a unique string and use it as an encryption/decryption key for an app

This way i could just open an app, touch the screen with the card and it would get authorized.
But here's the problem:

- It shouldn't matter where you place the card on a screen, because the card would be pretty small to fit various screen sizes
- The rectangle in which we can randomly position the 9 "fingers" would optimally be 4.5cm x 3cm
- The "finger" itself is only recognized as a touch if it is about a 6mm circle (not sure if this can be made smaller)

I figured we could find the left-top "finger" and get every other "finger's" X and Y difference from it. Then concatenate the resulting numbers into a string and use it as a decryption/encryption key. So basically:

```
key = concat(X2 - X1, Y2 - Y1, X3 - X1, Y3 - Y1, ...)
```

But i think such an approach would have very few possible combinations (given a relatively small card size and a relatively big "finger") and one could easily write a program to generate all possible combinations and break the key in no time. Am i right about this? If so, how could i improve this?

Thanks for your thoughts

**UPDATE 1**: actually tried it out on iOS. The result is not promising, since the "fingers" get detected differently each time. The distance between them varies significantly (by as much as 40 pixels!). So i guess this is not as easy as i expected, since the OS seems to detect the touch differently each time for the same two circles.

Comment: Since this sounds like you'd be targeting mobile devices, have you considered scanning a matrix code with the builtin camera instead?

Comment: That's too much trouble on the end user (me) part and also - this is a fun project, keyword being "fun" :) It's just something i want to try out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is lacking some relevant information: how far apart need the circles be so that the system can still distinguish them? What resolution can you realistically expect for the circle centers? And by “6mm circle”, do you mean 6mm diameter or radius (or even circumference)?

Lacking details, I'll make some pretty rough approximations. I'll start by requiring that two of the circles will be placed in opposite corners of the card. That way, you can find them by looking for a pair with maximal distance, and from that compute the orientation and size of the card and correct for that. This leaves 7 fingers to be placed randomly. I'll assume 1mm resolution, and restrict myself to a 45×30mm area. Which means 39×24=936 positions per circle, for a total of 936<sup>7</sup>≈6,3×10<sup>20</sup>≈2<sup>69</sup> combinations. OK, this does not exclude overlapping circles. But since the card is still rather sparsely covered, that shouldn't amount to too much. I'd say 64 bit of entropy (i.e. 2<sup>64</sup> possible combinations) should be reasonable even if you enforce non-overlapping circles. If you can really detect the circle centers with the required resolution, that is. This should be sufficient security for most applications. Far better than 8-letter passwords, but worse than the symmetric keys usually used for e.g. AES.

Since all of this depends very much on the resolution, it might be worthwhile to investigate that aspect first. Usually you'll get pixel coordinates for your finger positions, but it would be expecting too much to assume that you'd always get the pixel coordinate closest to the center of your circle. So you might start by writing a small application which draws a 6mm circle and records coordinates it receives. Then place a 6mm artificial circle in that drawn one a large number of times. Look how far the recorded positions differ from the center of circle. Take the maximum of those differences, perhaps after removing outliers. I'd add a pixel or two to that, to account for rounding errors due to the rotation of the card. Then turn that pixel count back into a metric length. This is the resolution you can expect. You might have to do this for several devices. If you do perform these experiments, let me know what you find and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: MvG, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, i don't know yet how far apart the circles should be, but they shouldn't overlap or even touch.  Having that in mind, only the first circle would have lots of possible positions, and all the others would probably have way fewer options, correct?

Comment: @Marius: note I updated my question. Latter circles would have fewer options, but not far fever. You can place all circles in a 30×12mm strip with room to spare. So the area not covered by circles is always larger than 30×33mm, even for the last circle. That's the kind of thought upon which I based my last approximation of the 64 bit or more.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the change in your answer. Somehow it's difficult to believe that there's so many possible combinations in such a small area, but then again, i am totally clueless in math so i'll just trust your opinion on this.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you meant by resolution for circle centers. Could you explain please? I'll be trying it out on an iOS device as soon as i find the time for that so i guess i'll always end up with pixel values (not even sure if they'll be more precise than integers yet as well). And by 6mm circle i meant diameter.

Comment: MvG - thanks for the explanation on the resolution. But correct me if i'm wrong here - does it really matter what the device considers as finger's center? If i have a card that doesn't change and the "fingers" don't move or change shape on it - then whatever the touchscreen detects - it should detect the same point every time. And if that's so - it shouldn't matter where on that virtual finger the point is as long as it is in the same place every time.

Comment: Tested it out with 2 "fingers". Unfortunately, the distance between touches differs significantly each time (see my original post for updates). I guess i need something with a printed circuit, rather than a DIY approach to be more precise.

Comment: @Marius: What is 40px in mm?

Comment: 15cm is 768px on an ipad so 40px is about 7.8mm. I'd say this is a very large margin of error.

Comment: @Marius: That would suggest a 5×6 or even 4×6 grid, amounting to 14,307,150 [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) (24 bit) resp. 1,307,504 combinations (20 bit).